# Python: How to only retain elements from all previous sublists while iterating over list?

Tags: python, list, loops, integer, list-comprehension

So this is what I have:

```
 lst = [[1,4,5,9], [4,5,7,9], [6,2,9], [4,5,9], [4,5]]
```

And I want to make a new list where the sublists only have the elements that are shared with ALL the previous sublists.

It should look like this:

```
new_lst = [[1,4,5,9], [4,5,9], [9], [9], []]
```

I tried converting the integers to strings and iterating over it, but I can't seem to get the right result. I'm new to python, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: That isn't valid Python code. Did you mean to add commas between the sublists?

Comment: You should show what you've tried, to show you have at least made an effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the items, you can use a `set` based approach:

```
last = set(lst[0])
res = [lst[0]]
for item in lst[1:]:
    last &= set(item)
    res.append(list(last))
```

Here, `res` contains the resulting list of lists. The important line is `last &= set(item)` which calculates the intersection between the previous and the current item.

Comment: How would you go about doing this from the right side? I tried using lst[-1] instead of lst[0], and for the loop I did lst[:-2:-1] but it doesn't seem to work .

Comment: You'll start with `lst[-1]` and iterate over `lst[-2::-1]`, which basically iterates everything in reverse.

Comment: Simpler: `… res = []; for item in lst: …`. Also, use `sorted` instead of `list` for deterministic output.

Comment: To go right-to-left: `for item in reversed(lst): …`.

Comment: True, but iterating over the full list would do one additional list intersection, which I wanted to avoid. Using `sorted` is certainly possible, but it's not clear what the OP's use case is and I thus presented the simplest solution.

Comment: @DavidZwicker In the absence of sizing information, you don't know that `lst[1:]` would be faster than the additional intersection (both are O(n)). So, as per your second point, you should go for the simplest solution.

Comment: I'm not claiming that any solution is superior – in fact, it's likely that it doesn't matter performance-wise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

```
from itertools import accumulate
new_lst = map(list,accumulate(map(set,lst), set.intersection))
print(list(new_lst))
```

which produces

```
[[1, 4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 9], [9], [9], []]
```

but it doesn't guarantee the items of the sublists will be in the same order.

In case you do care about the order of the items, you can do it manually

```
last = set(lst[0])
new_lst = [lst[0]]
for l in lst[1:]:
    new_els = [n for n in l if n in last]
    new_lst.append(new_els)
    last &= set(new_els)

print(new_lst)
```

Or just ignore sets and use lists instead, but sets are faster, since they are hashed and intersection is a core functionality.

Comment: I like that solution, but I think it does not preserve the order of the items in the sublists, since it also uses set interactions.

Answer (score 0):

One line answer:

```
>>> from functools import reduce   # for forward compatible.
>>> lst = [[1,4,5,9], [4,5,7,9], [4,5,7,9], [4,5,9], [4,5]]
>>> [list(reduce(lambda x,y: set(x)&set(y), lst[:i+1])) for i in range(len(lst))]
[[1, 4, 5, 9], [9, 4, 5], [9], [9], []]
```

The explanation:

```
[1, 4, 5, 9] = list(set([1, 4, 5, 9]))
[9, 4, 5] = list(set([1, 4, 5, 9]) & set([4,5,7,9]))
[9] = list(set([1, 4, 5, 9]) & set([4,5,7,9]) & set([4,5,7,9]))
...
```

in the `i`'st loop,  it should be union the items in `lst[:i+1]`.